# Angularjs Uncaught ReferenceError on injected service into directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

Still finding my way with angular and I'm getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: y is not defined" on the line ".directive('y',[y,function(y){" . It's like it hasn't loaded the service. I also tried moving the scripts from the bod to the head but nothing do.

```
    angular.module('fofApp', ['appRoutes'])
    .factory('y',['$rootscope',function($rootScope) {
        return {val: "he"};
    }])
    .directive('yow',[y,function(y){
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            template: "<h1>aaaaah</h1>"
        };
    }]);
```

My html is

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body ng-app="fofApp">
  <yow></yow>
 <script src="libs/angular/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="js/app.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minification protection when using dependency injection requires strings as the first arguments (to match the order/number of the parameters passing into the function), which is always the *last* argument.

Change that y in your directive to a string. Like so:

```
.directive('yow',['y',function(y){
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u4v4cafm/ (no errors in console)

Comment: it appears that WAS the case.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem, but factory expects you to return an object. Try changing it to:

```
angular.module('fofApp', ['appRoutes'])
    .factory('y',['$rootscope',function($rootScope) {
        return { value :"he" }
    }])
```